# Selenium Manual Intervention

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have automated some processing in Selenium to interact with a web page to create entries into a system.

My problem is, sometimes the data mismatch slightly, and I can't process that.

What I need to happen is I try to find it, if I find an exact match, done.If I dont find an exact match, i need to pause and let a user do this peice for me. If I can't find an exact match, I need to pause processing, allow the user to do this step of the process, and click a button saying "Next" to move onto the next step when they are done.

There is a datagrid that looks somewhat like this.

```
CheckBox     TransactionType      Date              Amount
   []           Pending           1-7-2020          12.39
   []           Cancelled         1-9-2020          16.89
   []           Complete          1-12-2020         102.38
```

I get a request to process a transaction with a Date of 1-6-2020 and an amount of 12.39 that is pending. So I use the below code to find the transaction, process it.

```
        //Fing the datagrid element on the page.
        var dataGrid = SeleniumBrowser.FindElement(By.XPath(@"XPATH"));

        //Get the datarows in the element
        var dataRows = dataGrid.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));

        //filter the the data row objects, ignore the other junk.
        foreach (var datarow in dataRows.Where(qq => qq.TagName == "tr" && qq.Displayed == true && qq.GetAttribute("class").Contains("Row")))
        {
            //Get the child elements of the datarow
            var dataRowChildElements = datarow.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));

            //This contains one a value element like date or transaction type, see if it matches
            foreach (var childElement in dataRowChildElements)
            {
                //The elements im looking for have this attribute, the rest is trash.
                if (childElement.IsAttributePresent("data-attribute-name"))
                {
                    if (childElement.Text == "TEXT IM LOOKING FOR")
                    {
                        //Found my elemnt, grab it and click it.
                        var mycb = cb.Where(qqq => qqq.GetAttribute("class").Contains("checkbox chkBxCtl")).FirstOrDefault();
                        mycb.Click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mismatch slightly"? Are you getting an error? Where is the error happening?

Comment: So the customer gave me a date of 1-6 but the day is actually 1-7

Comment: Ok. But I cannot see in your code where you are looking for that date. Can you post an abbreviated snippet of the HTML? Also, you have redacted or changed some of your code (like the XPATH and "TEXT IM LOOKING FOR". Please include that. We need a [repro] or we cannot help you.